# Duplicating rows of all master tables using INSERT INTO... SELECT, when there are referenced keys

Tags: sql, mysql, stored-procedures

We have the following master tables in our mysql lab database (there are more tables but I simplified it to two tables and less columns):

test_components

```
id (PK)
component_name
units
lab_id
```

ref_ranges

```
id (PK)
component_id (references test_components.id)
min
max
lab_id
```

Till now, lab_id was storing only one value `lab001`. As per new requirements, I have to accommodate another lab in this database, and make a copy of all the master data for `lab002`.

I used the following procedure to do so:

```
START TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO test_components(component_name, units, lab_id)
SELECT component_name, units, 'lab002'
FROM test_components
WHERE lab_id = 'lab001';

INSERT INTO ref_ranges(component_id, min, max, lab_id)
SELECT component_id, min, max, 'lab002'
FROM ref_ranges
WHERE lab_id = 'lab001';

COMMIT;
```

As you can see, the error here is that the values that got inserted into `ref_ranges`.`component_id` were duplicates of those for `lab001` and not the new auto-incremented `test_component`.`id` values.

How can I modify the procedure so that it will pick the correct `test_component`.`id` for `lab002` to be inserted in `ref_ranges`.`component_id` ?

Answer (score 1):

For this to work properly, you need some more constraints

The combination of component_name, units must be unique for every lab, better ever make (component_name,lab_id ) UNIQUE

When they aren't uinique the subquery must be changed to a LIMIt 1 wit an ORDEr BY

```
START TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO test_components(component_name, units, lab_id)
SELECT component_name, units, 'lab002'
FROM test_components
WHERE lab_id = 'lab001';

INSERT INTO ref_ranges(component_id, `min`, `max`, lab_id)
SELECT ( SELECT id FROM test_components
  WHERE lab_id =  'lab002' AND (component_name, units) IN
  (SELECT component_name, units FROM test_components WHERE id =  r1.component_id))
  , `min`, `max`, 'lab002'
FROM ref_ranges r1
WHERE lab_id = 'lab001';

COMMIT;
```

> ```
> Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

> ```
> Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

> ```
> Query was empty
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM test_components
```

| id | component_name | units | lab_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | compA | 1 | lab001 |
| 2 | compB | 2 | lab001 |
| 3 | compA | 1 | lab002 |
| 4 | compB | 2 | lab002 |

```
SELECT * FROM ref_ranges
```

| id | component_id | min | max | lab_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0.00 | 5.00 | lab001 |
| 2 | 2 | 0.00 | 10.00 | lab001 |
| 3 | 3 | 0.00 | 5.00 | lab002 |
| 4 | 4 | 0.00 | 10.00 | lab002 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Wb7UyRZ5)

Comment: Actually, what I want is `ref_ranges.component_id` to be 3 and 4 for lab002 (since `component_id` holds a foreign key referencing the primary key `test_components.id`). 
What you have achieved in your solution is the same as what I achieved using my procedure.

Comment: oh sorry i switched the column names, this happens, when i use designs from other people, because it is malpractrice to have the same column name for multiple tables in a normalized table.  i corrected the column name